# Flutter apk not getting internet permission net::ERR_CACHE_MISS message

Tags: android, flutter, webview, android-manifest

When I build an apk with `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` and install it on my android phone. The internet does not work on the app for some reason. I have enable the internet permission on the androidManifest.xml

It works well when I debugg it and run it on simulator, the app gets internet in that case but not when is build as a signed apk.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tempo.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Nueva_temporada">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm using youtube_player_flutter and webview which both require internet access and they are both down. The only one that give an error is webview with "net::ERR_CACHE_MISS message".

flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1052], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: try this if you are using android studio then right click on your project folder and try to open project in flutter option and open in android module in new window and then go to build option and then create your signed build.

Comment: Hello, I followed the steps but unfortunately it still show the error and my app does not have access to the internet. Thank you, if you have any other suggestion please let me know.